# I have created a shopping list to be use in a cell phone. When running in a cell phone and during the scrolling vertical action I get cropped lines

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using google html service for this vegetables shopping list project. The issue is when running this in a cell phone scrolling down to view more products from this list I will get cropped lines and eventually a blank screen. I am using meta viewpoint statement in this project so it can work in mobile devices.
Please advise what do I need to do to solve this cropped lines problem. Here are the sources of the GS and the html file.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var id = e.parameter.RecId;
  Logger.log(id);
  
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('workpage1');
  template.id = id; 
  Logger.log(template.id);
  return template.evaluate()
     .setTitle('First HTLM')
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME); 
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
  </head>
  <body>
 
  <form id="myForm" class="p-2 border border-light rounded bg-light" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)"> <!-- Call JavaScript function "handleFormSubmit" -->
    <p style="font-size:5vw"class="h5 mb-5 text-center">Informacion del Cliente</p>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <input type="text" id="RecId" name="RecId" value="" style="display: none">
    <div class="form-group" style="font-size:5vw">
        <label for="name" >Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" required style="font-size:5vw">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6" style="font-size:5vw">
        <label for="Direccion">Direccion:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Direccion" name="Direccion" placeholder="Direccion de entrega" required style="font-size:5vw">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="font-size:5vw">
        <label for="NroCelular">Celular:</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="NroCelular" name="NroCelular" placeholder="Nro de Celular" required style="font-size:5vw">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
         <div class="form-group col-xs-6" style="font-size:5vw">
              <p>Forma de Pago:</p> 
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:5vw">
                   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Pago" id="Efectivo" value="Efectivo" required style="font-size:5vw">
                   <label class="form-check-label" for="Efectivo">Efectivo</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:5vw">
                   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Pago" id="TarjCredito" value="TarjCredito" required style="font-size:5vw">
                   <label class="form-check-label" for="TarjCredito">Tarj Credito</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="font-size:5vw">
                   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Pago" id="Yappy" value="Yappy" required style="font-size:5vw">
                   <label class="form-check-label" for="Yappy">Yappy</label>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>   
    <table id="example" class="a table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:5vw">Qty</th>
                <th style="font-size:5vw">Description</th>
                <th style="font-size:5vw">Unit</th>
                <th style="font-size:5vw">Price</th>
            </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="AjiChombo" name="AjiChombo" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Aji Chombo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Apio" name="Apio" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Apio</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="CebollaAmarilla" name="CebollaAmarilla" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Cebolla Amarilla</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Cebollina" name="Cebollina" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Cebollina</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="CilantroChino" name="CilantroChino" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Cilantro Chino</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Coco" name="Coco" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Coco</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Culantro" name="Culantro" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Culantro</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Fresa" name="Fresa" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Fresa</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Guineo" name="Guineo" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Guineo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="HongosNacionales" name="HongosNacionales" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Hongos Nacionales</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Lechuga" name="Lechuga" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Lechuga</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Maiz" name="Maiz" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Maiz</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="ManzanaRoja" name="ManzanaRoja" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Manzana Roja</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="ManzanaVerde" name="ManzanaVerde" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Manzana Verde</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Melon" name="Melon" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Melon</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Papaya" name="Papaya" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Papaya</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PapayaVerde" name="PapayaVerde" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Papaya Verde</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Pera" name="Pera" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Pera</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Unidad</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Perejil" name="Perejil" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Perejil</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PimentonAmarillo" name="PimentonAmarillo" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Pimenton Amarillo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PimentonNaranjado" name="PimentonNaranjado" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Pimenton Naranjado</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PimentonVerde" name="PimentonVerde" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Pimenton Verde</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PlatanoMaduro" name="PlatanoMaduro" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Platano Maduro</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Platanoverde" name="Platanoverde" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Platano verde</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Raspaduras" name="Raspaduras" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Raspaduras</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Unidad</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Sandia" name="Sandia" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Sandia</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Uvasconsemillas" name="Uvasconsemillas" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Uvas con semillas</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Uvassinsemillas" name="Uvassinsemillas" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Uvas sin semillas</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Yuca" name="Yuca" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Yuca</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Zanahoria" name="Zanahoria" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Zanahoria</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PapayaVerde1" name="PapayaVerde1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Papaya Verde</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Pera1" name="Pera1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Pera</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Unidad</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Perejil1" name="Perejil1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Perejil</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PimentonAmarillo1" name="PimentonAmarillo1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Pimenton Amarillo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PimentonNaranjado1" name="PimentonNaranjado1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Pimenton Naranjado</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PimentonVerde1" name="PimentonVerde1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Pimenton Verde</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PlatanoMaduro1" name="PlatanoMaduro1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Platano Maduro</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Platanoverde1" name="Platanoverde1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Platano verde</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Raspaduras1" name="Raspaduras1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Raspaduras</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Unidad</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Sandia1" name="Sandia1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Sandia</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Uvasconsemillas1" name="Uvasconsemillas1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Uvas con semillas</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Uvassinsemillas1" name="Uvassinsemillas1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Uvas sin semillas</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Yuca1" name="Yuca1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Yuca</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Zanahoria1" name="Zanahoria1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Zanahoria</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="AjiChombo1" name="AjiChombo1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Aji Chombo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Apio1" name="Apio1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Apio</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="CebollaAmarilla1" name="CebollaAmarilla1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Cebolla Amarilla</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Cebollina1" name="Cebollina1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Cebollina</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="CilantroChino1" name="CilantroChino1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Cilantro Chino</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Coco1" name="Coco1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Coco</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Culantro1" name="Culantro1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Culantro</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Fresa1" name="Fresa1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Fresa</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Guineo1" name="Guineo1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Guineo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="HongosNacionales1" name="HongosNacionales1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Hongos Nacionales</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Lechuga1" name="Lechuga1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Lechuga</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Maiz1" name="Maiz1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Maiz</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="ManzanaRoja1" name="ManzanaRoja1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Manzana Roja</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="ManzanaVerde1" name="ManzanaVerde1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Manzana Verde</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Mazo</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$2.50</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="Melon1" name="Melon1" maxlength="3" size="3" style="font-size:5vw"></td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Melon</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">Libra</td>
                <td style="font-size:5vw">$1.50</td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
       
    </table> 
    
    <button type="submit" style="font-size:5vw" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar Cambios</button>
    <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset" value="Inicializar" style="font-size:5vw">
  </form>   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the viewport metaTag server side. See duplicate answer linked above(along with the comments chain) for more details.

Comment: That fixed this issue.Thks for providing this info.